# Store values of 2-dimenssional range (i,j) recalculated N times to a 2-dimensional range (N,i*j)

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a 2-dimensional range (i, j) like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0
```

I want to copy&paste it to another sheet like this:

```
1 6 2 7 3 8 4 9 5 0
```

I need to recalculate the 2-dim range many times and store the results on another sheet, where each row stores one iteration.
Right now I store all calculations in a array (N, i*j) using two for-loops and then paste all itearations on another sheet.

Is there a faster way to do that?
Current code:

```
Dim a(1 To 100, 1 To 10) As Double

For iter = 1 To 100

    Calculate
    For i = 1 To 2
        For j = 1 To 5
            a(iter, i + j * (i - 1)) = Cells(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

Next iter

With Sheets("results")
    Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(100, 2 * 5)) = a
End With
```

**UPD:**
After each "calculate" the values of the initial range change. The example just illustrates how the values from 2-d range should be stored in one row.

**UPD2:** 
Corrected my current code

Comment: can you just use `=` in the results book and fill down by vba?

Comment: What do you mean by "iterations"? I don't understand what's the result you want...

Comment: After each "calculate" the values of the initial range change. The example  just illustrates how the values from 2-d range should be stored in one row.

Comment: The problem is that your segment "calculate" always produce the same result for the array `a` (5, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)... So you'll reproduce the same result on the 100 lines...

Comment: There are formulas in each cell which give different results after recalculation

Comment: You can speed it up by getting rid of all `Cells()` calls and load up the values into a memory array `tmp = Range("A2").Resize(2,5).Value`, then manipulate the values into memory direct before outputting the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It gives your desired output and only uses two loops (instead of three)

```
' For loop
Dim i As Long, j As Long
' Initalise array
Dim tmp(1 To 100, 1 To 10) As Variant

'Loop through all rows in already initalised array
For i = LBound(tmp, 1) To UBound(tmp, 1)
    'Calculate to get updated row contents
    Calculate
    'Loop through each column in row
    'The Round and divided by two is to calculate the number of columns concerned instead of the number in the array
    For j = LBound(tmp, 2) To Round((UBound(tmp, 2) + 0.1) / 2)
        'First row
        tmp(i, (j + j - 1)) = Cells(1, j).Value2
        'Second row
        ' If incase the array is initalised to an odd number otherwise this would be out of range
        If j * 2 <= UBound(tmp, 2) Then
            tmp(i, j * 2) = Cells(2, j).Value2
        End If
    Next j
Next i
' Write back to sheet
With Sheets("results").Cells(1, 1)
    Range(.Offset(0, 0), .Offset(UBound(tmp, 1) - 1, UBound(tmp, 2) - 1)) = tmp
End With
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew that the answer is to loop through each column, but don't know how to make it quick.

Comment: Is it faster then your original code? Also to change the number of columns just change the second dimension of the array. It should figure everything else out for itself.

Comment: Your code is about 40% faster than mine. And I can speed it up a lit bit more, since I can replace UBound and LBound with numbers.

Comment: @TimurMardanov I doubt you'll see much of a performance gain by doing that I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim rData As Range
    Dim iter As Long
    Dim lNumIterations As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim a() As Double
    Dim aAfterCalc As Variant

    Set rData = Sheets("Data").Range("A1:E2")
    lNumIterations = 100
    ReDim a(1 To lNumIterations, 1 To rData.Rows.Count * rData.Columns.Count)

    For iter = 1 To lNumIterations
        k = 0
        Calculate
        aAfterCalc = rData.Value
        For j = 1 To rData.Columns.Count
            For i = 1 To rData.Rows.Count
                k = k + 1
                a(iter, k) = aAfterCalc(i, j)
            Next i
        Next j

    Next iter

    Sheets("results").Range("A1").Resize(lNumIterations, UBound(a, 2)).Value = a

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code does just what I want, but it is not faster than my original one

Comment: @TimurMardanov Due to having to wait for the workbook to calculate, you can't really get any faster than this (or your original one).  Your original code had a problem with column assignment in your array `a` though.  This code fixes that and makes it so you only have to update the range instead of making several small changes to get the code to work properly so it is easier to adjust and maintain.

Comment: I agree with you about  delays due to the workbook calculations. But saving results takes about 40% of all execution time since I have seven 60-by-20 ranges which need to be saved. I think that there is a way to avoid cell-by-cell copy. I tried to copy column-by-column using pastespecial and transpose, but it was slower.

Comment: @TimurMardanov Updated code to convert the rData into an array after each iteration.  Hopefully that should help speed it up.  Let me know if there's any performance gain.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get you, but something like this

```
Sub test()

Dim a() As Variant
Dim b() As Variant

a = Range("a1:e1").Value
b = Range("a2:e2").Value

For x = 1 To 5
    Range("H1").Offset(0, x).Value = a(1, x)
    Range("H1").Offset(0, 5 + x).Value = b(1, x)
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: The numer of rows in the original range is much bigger than 2, so I can't create a variant for each row.

Comment: loop it using my code as the base. so a goes from a1-e1 to a3 to e3

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub this()
    Dim this As Variant, counter As Long, that As Integer, arr() As Variant
    counter = 0
    this = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange
    For i = LBound(this, 2) To UBound(this, 2)
            counter = counter + 2
            ReDim Preserve arr(1 To 1, 1 To counter)
            arr(1, counter - 1) = this(1, i)
            arr(1, counter) = this(2, i)
    Next i
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, 1), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, counter)).Value2 = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code produces 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 and I need 1 6 2 7 3 8 4 9 5 0

Comment: @TimurMardanov see my eidt, this time I got it right, sorry

Comment: `ReDim Preserve` is painfully slow. A faster way would be to `ReDim` the array to a large size and then after the loop `ReDim Preserve` down to it's correct size. This way you only have to do it once. It'll make your code much faster and you'll definitely notice the speed improvement when you're doing a lot of iterations like in this case

Comment: Thanks I wasnt aware that was a huge overhead.